# Cannot unpause game when bringing app back to Foreground

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

SpriteKit is automatically pausing my app when it goes into the background.  This is fine, except it stays paused when the app becomes active again. I'm trying to un-pause the game in the appropriate application events, to no avail. I'm manually un-pausing the two `SKViews` and the game `Scene` that constitute the app. From inside the AppDelegate file:

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {

    if let vw = self.window?.rootViewController {
        let gc = vw as! GameViewController
        let parView = gc.view as! SKView
        parView.paused = false
        gc.gameView.paused=false
        gc.gameScene.paused=false
        println("paused = \(gc.gameScene.paused)")

    }

}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

    if let vw = self.window?.rootViewController {
        let gc = vw as! GameViewController
        let parView = gc.view as! SKView
        parView.paused = false

        gc.gameView.paused=false
        gc.gameScene.paused=false
        println("paused = \(gc.gameScene.paused)")

    }

}
```

At the end I print the pause state. If I hit the device's `Home` key and then return to the app, it prints `false` as desired. However, somewhere (not by my code) this is being immediately set back to `true`, and the game remains paused.

**Update**

I overrode the scene's `paused` property, and it is definitely being set back to `true` after I un-pause in the given events. Confusing, because from reading other questions, the typical behavior of sprite kit is to automatically *un-pause* the game when the app is reactivated. Yet it's doing the exact opposite for me.

Comment: Find all the places where you set it to true - one of these must be being invoked.  Set breakpoints

Comment: @Paulw11 - I never set paused to true.  It pauses automatically when the game goes into the background.

Comment: I had same problem. I solved it by implementing `NSNotification` during entering background and foreground in my game view and implementing my logic in Notification for pausing and unpausing.

Comment: @JafferSheriff Sorry, but I don't see how that's any different.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding: I tried posting a notification in `appDidBecomeActive`:  `NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("UnPauseNotification", object:nil)` - but this will occur at the same time as my code above, and paused still gets set to true afterwards.

Comment: The thing I meant was you may be having your own pause button in game view and you may want to fire it when app enter background. So this is default behaviour of all games and it is possible only by having notification in particular game view. More over SpriteKit by default implements pausing and unpausing logic in the back . So you have to take care of that too. Unpausing is automatically handled by spritekit so try removing every code from `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Comment: @JafferSheriff `Unpausing is automatically handled by sprite kit...` - So I had thought too. But even if I remove _all_ my code in the `AppDelegate` file (i.e., no `paused` commands whatsoever, in the entire application), sprite kit is _pausing_ the game when the app becomes active, which is apparently the exact opposite of what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I basically gave up on trying to control whether the game pauses/resumes during the app's state changes. Instead I overrode the scene's `paused` property, so now I can just detect whenever sprite kit decides to pause or resume, and handle that accordingly.  My suspicion is that my hierarchy of `SKViews` in my app might not be conventional, and maybe caused sprite kit difficulty in controlling the scene state, but that's only a guess.